# ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64'), when doing clustering

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I get the error mentioned in the question when I try to do the elbow method, which I'm doing to do KMeans clustering.

**Steps I took to solve the issue:**

****1.** Checked NaN and infinity:**

`np.isnan(df3.any())` output=False

`np.isfinite(df3.all())` output=True

****2.** Tried to reduce the value of my float64 number by using `round()`:**

`df4 = df3.round({'VolumeRatio_Log':4, 'DollarMillionRatio_Log':4})`

*This didn't solve the error message*

****3.** Converting the data type from float64 to int64:**

`df3.column = df3.column.astype('Int64')` I get the following error

> TypeError: cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64

`df3.column= df3.column.astype(np.int64)`I get the following error

> ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

*Can't manage to convert and don't know if it will solve my main error (in the title of the question)*

*****4.*** Tried doing Hierarchical clustering instead of KMeans - instead of elbow method, I used the dendrogram and get the following error:**

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 722. GiB for an array with shape (96845105253,) and data type float64

I don't know what I could do otherwise to solve the error message and make the code for the elbow method work.

As a reminder, the error message I'm trying to solve:
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

**Sample of my data:** *(the columns are logged)*

```
  col1    col2
  1.4494  4.2302
  0.3561  4.5876
  1.9148  4.8567
 ...
 -1.3172  8.2511
 -0.5452  6.5569
 -0.6241  4.8539
```

**Code I use for Elbow Method**

```
wcss = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init = 'k-means++', random_state = 42)
    kmeans.fit(X)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
plt.plot(range(1, 11), wcss)
plt.title('The Elbow Method')
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('WCSS')
plt.show()
```

**Error I get to be solved** : ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

**Code I use for Dendrogram:**

```
dendrogram = sch.dendrogram(sch.linkage(X, method = 'ward'))
plt.title('Dendrogram')
plt.xlabel('Observation points')
plt.ylabel('Euclidean distances')
plt.show()
```

Error I get: MemoryError: Unable to allocate 722. GiB for an array with shape (96845105253,) and data type float64

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the output of df3.isna().sum() and df3.info()? Where exactly does the ValueError occur?

Comment: Your checks in step 1 aren't doing what you think they are.  `np.isnan(df3.any())` is checking whether there's any data in `df3` and whether the resulting value (`True` or `False`) is `nan` (it isn't).  `np.isfinite(df3.all())` is checking wheter `df3` is all nonzero, and then whether the resulting value (`True` or `False`) is finite (it is).

Comment: @AndreS. output are all 0 and non-null. The error occur when doing the elbow method.

Comment: @DanielF thanks for the explanation, it helped me realize that some of my calculation was incorrect and gave me infinite values.